# Let $X = \{−1,0,1\}$ and $A =\mathcal{P}(X)$, and $R$ is defined on $A$ as for all sets $S,T \in A$, $\ldots$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $X = \{−1,0,1\}$ and $A = \mathcal{P}(X)$, and $R$ is defined on $A$ as for all sets $S,T \in A$,
$$
SRT \Longleftrightarrow \text{the sum of the elements in $S$ equals the sum of the elements in $T$}.
$$ Find the distinct equivalence classes of $R$.

Comment: There are $8$ subsets of $X$. What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly none, I've been busy dealing with my wife having mobility issues due to an accident and taking care of my kids whilst working overnight so I'm a tad exhausted and having brain farts on what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: It seems dramatically faster to actually do the problem than to ask what its solution is and wait, especially as it isn't hard. Write down the $8$ subsets of $X$; find the sum of each (add up its elements); group by the sums. Is any of that puzzling?

Comment: Subsets should be  {},{-1},{0 },{1},{-1,0 },{-1,1},{0 ,1},{-1,0 ,1} right?

Comment: Exactly, that's right. Now tag each with the sum of its members (empty sum = 0).

Comment: So, $0, -1, 0, ...$ for the sum of the subsets in the order you wrote them...

Comment: (PS Not to be insensitive: sorry about your travails & your wife's accident.)

Comment: So 0,-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0? What do I do with these

Comment: Do you understand what an equivalence relation is? Which of these sets are equivalent, according to the relation $R$ that your question defines? which are not? Group the equivalent sets together into sets; the resulting sets (of sets of numbers) are the equivalence classes.

Comment: So I'm guessing there are going to be 4 partitions that I have to group them into right @BrianO?

Comment: There can't be 4. Two sets are equivalent $\iff$ their sums are the same. How many different sums are there? Don't guess, deduce: the problem means what is says & says what it means.

Comment: One set will be:{},{0},{-1,1}, and {-1,0,1}

Comment: Second set: {-1,0} and {-1}

Comment: Last set: {1}, {0,1} right @BrianO or did I just completely botch that?

Comment: Yep, You got it :)

Comment: Congrats, good going.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what would exactly be my answer? The equivalence sets of R are so and so and then list each set? Would you also be able to help me out with the other question you commented on? I posted what I think Q would be in that question but the other person apparently A. Didn't see it or B. Completely ignored it. @BrianO

Comment: The equivalence *classes* of $R$ are: 1. {{}, {0}, {-1,1}, {-1,0,1}}  2. {{1}, {0,1}} and 3. {{1}, {0,1}}.  What's the link to the other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsets should be $\{\},\{-1\},\{0\},\{1\},\{-1,0\},\{-1,1\},\{0,1\},\{-1,0,1\}$

One set will be: $\{\},\{0\},\{-1,1\}$, and $\{-1,0,1\}$

Second set: $\{-1,0\}$ and $\{-1\}$

Last set: $\{1\},\{0,1\}$

The equivalence classes of $RR$ are:

1. $\{\{\},\{0\},\{-1,1\},\{-1,0,1\}\}$
2. $\{\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$
3. $\{\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$